# How to remove white spaces after a paragraph?

Tags: vertical-spacing

I want to remove blank spaces after this paragraph as shown in the following picture:

[image]

I tried with no success :

```
\usepackage{float}
\FloatBarrier
```

Code portion:

```
 ------   paragraph1 --------
    
    \FloatBarrier
    
        \begin{table}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}
                \hline
                --- some data table 1 ---                             
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
         
        
            
        
        
        \FloatBarrier
        
   ------- secondly , we conclude that ...paragraph2-------
        
        \FloatBarrier
        \begin{table}
            
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}
                \hline
                ----some data table 2-------
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        
        \end{table}
        
        
        \FloatBarrier
        
   ------ paragraph3-------
```

In fact , i'm wanting a simple way to force tables to be positionned after the wanted paragraph.

Thank you a lot for help !

Comment: Do you use a two side documentclass? If so, adding raggedbottom to the preamble could help

Comment: Hi Tou Mou and welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please post a MWE that shows your code at this location?

Comment: A guess: are you using `[H]` float specifiers? Don't. Now you know why.

Comment: @TobiBS ok wait a second !

Comment: @daleif  , I used \begin{table}[h!]...\end{table}  before in the document but not in this part.

Comment: Please make it into a full (but minimal) example that others can copy and test. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: @leandriis  , no is a single side document.

Comment: @daleif , i reduced the code .

Comment: I resolved the problem using the [hbt!] option

Comment: Thank you all for your precious help !

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has solved the problem himself, as stated in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ------   paragraph1 --------
    
    \FloatBarrier
    
        \begin{table}
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}
                \hline
                --- some data table 1 ---                             
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
         
        
            
        
        
        \FloatBarrier
        
  %% ------- secondly , we conclude that ...paragraph2// here you should add  [hbt!] option after \begin{table} -------%%
        
        \FloatBarrier
        \begin{table} [hbt!]
            
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}
                \hline
                ----some data table 2-------
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        
        \end{table}
        
        
        \FloatBarrier
        
   ------ paragraph3-------
```